# Backup extensions, bookmarks and other customizations from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, backup, google-chrome-extensions

I am reinstalling my OS and I would like to keep the list of installed extensions, bookmarks and other customizations in my Google Chrome browser.

How can I re-create the setup on the new system?

Comment: What's your OS and do you just want to keep a list or actually *copy* your settings as they were?

Answer (score 9):

[Bon Gart's answer](https://superuser.com/a/420919/48078) explains the native way to do it, which only involves signing into your Google account. However, if you don't want to sign up with Google, or store your data with them, you can easily go ahead and archive your profile folder.

It's stored in the following location:

- **Windows XP:** `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
- **Vista, Windows 7:** `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
- **Mac OS X:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
- **Linux:** `~/.config/google-chrome/`

All you have to do is:

- Quit Chrome
- Copy the `User Data` folder contents somewhere safe
- After re-installing your OS, install Chrome*
- Run it once and close it again
- Copy the backup of your old `User Data` folder over the existing one in your new OS installation
- Start Chrome again and you should be running like before.

<sub>* I'd advise to install exactly the same version of Chrome though. If you install an older version, your profile will not be readable. Also, when switching OS, this method might *not* work.</sub>

Comment: I did it successfully with the entire User Data folder between two XP systems, but I'm pretty sure I copied extraneous info.

Answer (score 7):

**Re-Packaging as .crx:** For a more compact version of your extensions (rather than the unpacked, folder version), you can use Chrome to re-package them into **.crx** files. I use this when I notice I still have an extension that is no longer available on the Chrome Web Store, and therefore will not sync back.

- Open `Tools > Extensions`
- Click `Developer Mode`
- Click `Pack extension...`
- Click **Browse** next to `Extension Root Directory`
- Navigate your way to the `User Data` folder you copied (refer to **slhck**'s answer).
- Find the folder for the extension. There should be another folder named after the version number of your extension. Click that folder, then click `OK`.
- `Private File Key` is optional (as it states).
- Click `Pack Extension`

Voilá! Your new **.crx** file is in the same directory as the folder it was derived from. By the way, ever since a recent Google Chrome update, you have to open `Tools > Extensions` and drag your **.crx** file into the window to install 3rd party extensions (ie. not from Chrome Web Store).

<sub>*I just discovered this today and thought it would be helpful.</sub>

**EDIT:** One last piece of information is the means of identifying the extension. Somewhere within the extension folder (likely named something like: `apjhdoaiejppfmijnkopdcpjcngdlfvj`) you will find images that will contain the image for the extension's icon. This is the best way I know of to figure out what's what.

**EDIT:** In *chrome://extensions* click *Details* on the extension you want and it will tell you the ID in the address bar (e.g.: `id=apjhdoaiejppfmijnkopdcpjcngdlfvj`). It will be the name of the folder you want.

Comment: Can this still be used to Backup and Restore Extensions given new Chrome 44 locks a lot of things down? 
- Also, would this store the "local" storage, settings etc of the Extension or would that have to be backed up from elsewhere?

Comment: 2nd way to identify extension folder is to enable developer mode in chrome extension web-page then you will see the ID of extension, which actually is the name of the extension folder :)

Answer (score 4):

First, you make sure you are logged in to your Chrome Browser.  You know, click the wrench, and look for where it tells you that you are signed in.  If you are not, you need to do so.

Chrome will sync and backup a buttload of stuff for you.

> chrome://settings/personal

Put that in your browser, or just click the wrench, settings, and Personal Stuff.  The first option, Sign in... has an Advanced Button.  Click that to see exactly what gets synchronized to Google.  Or click that to decide what you want to sync.

So, really... anywhere you install Chrome, if you sign in as you, will give you access to all the goodies you have now.

**EDIT**

And yes, I tested this myself.  Just now.  Opened up one of the other computers, installed Chrome on it, signed into it, and watched my extensions get added before my eyes (the ones that show on the start page), and my bookmarks are there, etc.

Comment: … which of course only works if you have a Google account `&&` want to  store your data with them :)

Comment: @slhck that is a most excellent point.  Granted, one could always sign up for a Google account just for this purpose, and ignore all the other services that they offer.  But, that would mean just another account to keep track of.  Then again, having that extra account could be considered a valid trade off for the benefit of being able to sync your Chrome settings easily across any computer you use Chrome on.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I think this is one of the most convenient features they offer! I'm pretty sure though that a simple profile backup would fulfill the same purpose if it's really just about migrating to a new computer.

Comment: Yes, and they do have the feature to Import bookmarks and some of those settings from another browser, but not to easily Export those settings locally.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it suffice to just archive the Default profile in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`?

Comment: .... running out of machines to install Chrome on.... lol... oops, gotta close the current session to be able to copy it...

Comment: @slhck you are not wrong.  Worked like a charm.  Different machine, new Chrome install... account by the same name though, although I doubt that would have made a difference.  So, you should drop an answer in here with that, since it works, and doesn't require signing up for anything.

Comment: Well thanks for acting as a human guinea pig! Posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to backup my bookmarks to an .HTML file.  It was pretty straight forward and worked well.

Hope this helps.

**Bookmarks Export in Google Chrome**

> (1). Go to your bookmarks manager page.
>
> ```
> chrome://bookmarks/
> ```
>
> (2). On the right-hand side of the page click on the ellipse button
>   `(...)`, then `Export bookmarks`.
>
> (3). Save the .HTML file to a file directory of your choosing.  (HINT-
>   I saved in Dropbox so I can easily access it from another PC and can
>   recover the bookmarks.)
>
> (4). Then double-click the file, and all the webpages you have saved
>   to your bookmarks will open in the web browser.  You can open the file
>   in any browser (I tested... CHROME | IE), and it is a very nice format
>   that you can see all the favorited website.

**The Exported File**

My filepath: `bookmarks_google-chrome-(20190116).html`

```
C:\Users\[myUserName]\Dropbox\[myRootFolder]\Google Chrome\bookmarks_google-chrome-(20190116).html
```

My file opened in the IE browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think reinstallation is required for extensions since Chrome/Chromium/Canary is updated in an orderly manner.

There is [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-links-of-all-exten/cmeckkgeamghjhkepejgjockldoblhcb/related) to preserve names and links of extensions installed priorly.

Likewise, bookmark export option is present. Just Google it.