# How do I save all of the data from my Chrome browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

I'd like to save everything from my chrome browser and then reset my browser as new.

I'm on a Mac. I've looked around at threads on SE and they're generally out of date.

I tried to extract the data from this folder `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` into a SQLite database, but it gave me empty output.

Ideally, I'd save my history, cookies, bookmarks and any other data Chrome stores on browsing.

I'd like to get the browser history in a readable format, like a CSV or JSON file and the rest of the data in any particular format that can be accessed later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backup extensions, bookmarks and other customizations from Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/420900/backup-extensions-bookmarks-and-other-customizations-from-google-chrome)

Comment: That indicates how to save the data, but not how to extract it into a readable format.

Comment: That new line you've just added is meaningless for the majority of the data the browser stores. History and Bookmarks are useful in "readable" formats, but cookies and most of the other data is not designed to be meaningful to human eyes. What are you hoping to do with this data?

Comment: I'd like to look at Bookmarks, History, Extensions and Extension settings as reference tools in the future, in case I need to find a link or my settings. For the rest of it, I just want to make sure I don't lose anything when I clear Chrome.